# Is implementations not being interchangeable and having to cast often a code smell?

Tags: java, interfaces, code-smell, implementations

I'm building a small game similar to chess. I'd like to be able to reuse the structure for another version of checkers too. I'm modeling the games with interfaces (showing only relevant ones):

### RuleOrchestrator.class

```
public interface RuleOrchestrator {
    Collection<Move> allowedMoves(Player player, Move move);
}
```

### Player.class

```
public interface Player {
    Move getMove(Board board);
}
```

### AIEngine.class

```
public interface AIEngine {
    Move computeBestMove(Board board, RuleOrchestrator ruleOrchestrator);
}
```

The general design seems to be fine for both games. However, I find myself doing quite a few castings. After thinking about it, I have come to what looks like the root of the issue: I'm using the interfaces only to define the general workflow of the games, but many times the implementations are not interchangeable. The two implementations of `AIEngine` work with any `Board` and `RuleOrchestrator`, but almost every other concrete class works only with the concrete classes in their own "realm" (game).

### Chess.class

```
public class Chess implements Game {

    private final Player player1;
    private final Player player2;
    private final RuleOrchestrator ruleOrchestrator;
    private final Board board;

    public Chess(String player1, String player2, int size) {
        this.player1 = new HumanPlayer(player1);
        this.player2 = new HumanPlayer(player2);
        this.board = new ChessBoard(size);
        this.ruleOrchestrator = new ChessOrchestrator(board); // 1
    }
    // ...
}
```

### ChessOrchestrator.class

```
public class ChessOrchestrator implements RuleOrchestrator {
    private final Board board; // 2
    public ChessOrchestrator(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Move> allowedMoves(Player player, Move move) {
        // Do stuff
        ... ((ChessBoard)board).getKing(); // 3
        ChessMove chessMove = (ChessMove) move; // 4
        // More things
        // ...
    }
}
```

For instance, `ChessOrchestrator` expects to work with a chess board. It needs chess-specific info and calls methods specific to `ChessBoard`. It probably doesn't make sense to define the field at // 2 with type `Board`. Using `ChessBoard` would avoid having to cast. Then, I would need o either work directly with `ChessBoard` also in `Chess`, or casting in line // 1. Furthermore, `move` also needs to be cast to a `ChessMove` at // 4.

Not only I dislike these casts, but I'm afraid they're the symptom of a bigger problem. Is this a code smell? How can I avoid these castings and improve the app's design?

Comment: What is a "code smell?"

Comment: @RoberyHarvey You aren't familiar with [code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)? Or were you asking that to see if *he* was familiar with the proper definition?

Answer (score 7):

> How can I avoid these castings and improve the app's design?

This looks like a candidate for use of generic types.  A generic base could be written to provide basic workflow, though taking a type argument, meaning that for the `Chess` family you would supply `ChessBoard`.

You might have `IOrchestrator<BoardType>` interface, and therein you can declare methods that operate over `BoardType`.

You might further implement an abstract generic base class `Orchestrator<BoardType> implements IOrchestrator<BoardType>`.  This abstract class can provide a field `board` of type `BoardType` and some default method implementations for the interface.

You might then have `ChessOrchestrator extends Orchestrator<ChessBoard>`, which can use the field `board` of `BoardType` knowing it is a `ChessBoard`, hence without casting.

Comment: I doubt that the solution  is *generics*. It may reduce your casting problems, but IMHO  the root cause is that the games are not similar enough to share the same interfaces.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Why are they not similar enough? Does a chess board have anything other than a specific set of allowed moves?

Comment: @NickL *"Why are they not similar enough?"* We might think of some implementation where your board has only *generic* methods applyable to any game but the OP has this call:  `((ChessBoard)board).getKing();` which is not "generic" at all and highly coupled to a game that has "Kings". This means the OPs problem needs to be solven on *architecture* level. Looking for a "more generic" interface is not enough.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle you forgot that that call is made in `ChessOrchestrator`, which is specifically implemented for the chess game, and is not a generic class. If `board` would be generic, it would be of type `ChessBoard` for that class. This is exactly what generics is for.

Answer (score 3):

Implementations of the same interface that are not interchangeable violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and indeed in such cases the need to cast is a smell.

In essence, the implementing class violates the interface since it makes additional assumptions about the methods' input arguments, assumptions which are not a part of the interface. The code which uses the `RuleOrchestrator` interface must pass the right subtype of Board to the allowedMoves method, meaning that it must know something about the concrete implementation class of RuleOrchestrator which isn't expressed in the interface. This means that the consuming code is tightly coupled to the implementation.